# Android : Launch Skype to be in background

Tags: android, skype, autostart

I hope this is just a temporary problem and Skype allows an autostart feature.

I need to launch Skype so that it can receive Skype calls and video  calls, and then launch my app. I work with the elderly s simplicity is at a premium. My app runs continuously.

The following code seems to achieve this goal in a BOOT BroadcastReceiver.

```
        PackageManager  pmi = context.getPackageManager();
        String packageName ="com.skype.raider";     
        context.startActivity(pmi.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName));  
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",String.format("should launch Skype"));  
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MyApp.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("FromBoot",1);
        intent1.putExtras(bundle);
        try{ // hoping to schedule the start to after Skype has finished                
            Thread.sleep(20000);                 
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",String.format("error in delay loop"));  
                    }
        context.startActivity(intent1);
```

This launches Skype and waits 20s to get sorted out before launching my app. My app ends up on the screen (desired effect).

However, it has a tiny problem for most people, but a big one for me. After the first Skype call the Blue welcome screen of Skype stays up, and the user has to press back button. Effectively this makes ending a Skype call different depending on whether it is the first or subsequent calls.

Questions.

Can I close Skype from my app?

Can I detect that Skype is finished teh call from my app?

Comment: 1/ of course not. 2/ does skype broadcasts the information? if not, you may try to know which window is up, but that's hackish

Comment: To know which window is on top...private String getTopActivity(){
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String topPackageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();        
    Log.e("AutoStart","TopPackage : "+ topPackageName);
 return topPackageName;
} ** looks rather messy in a comment ** However knowing that Skype is topmost is not enough if the person is actually chatting on Skype!!!

Comment: there may be a particular activity on top that would suggest an ongoing call.